# Simplify using functional equations

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Is it possible to simplify assuming a functional equation, for examlpe to use that one function, g, is the invers of another, f.

```
Simplify[g[f[x]], g[f[x_]] == x]
```

just returns `g[f[x]]`, and similar for FullSimplify.

Comment: have you tried using `UpValues` for `g` like `g/:g[f[x_]]:=x` and then simplifying?

Comment: that works... Thanks

Comment: One additional comment: why `Simplify[g[f[x]], g[f[x_]] == x]` doesn't work is because Assumptions does not in general support patterns, and also there is an ordering issue of variable names. If you do `Simplify[g[f[x]], g[f[x]] == x[]]`, the replacement works.

Comment: A generalized simplification function with assumptions can be found here http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42607/simplify-equations-with-pattern-assumptions/42608#42608.

Answer (score 2):

As it was pointed out in the comments, `Assumptions` does not work with `Patterns`, but `ReplaceAll` works:

```
g[f[x]] /. g[f[_]] -> x
```

> ```
> x
> ```

On the other hand you can use `InverseFunction` because it can handle symbolic operations:

```
g = InverseFunction[f];
f[g[x]]
```

> ```
> x
> ```