# Assumptions with patterns

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, assumptions

I want that *Mathematica* assumes every symbol like `Subscript[s,i]` to be evaluate as a real and positive number. I have tried

```
$Assumptions = {Element[{h, k}, Integers], h > -1, k > -1, 
  Element[{Subscript[m, _], Subscript[s, _]}, Reals], Subscript[s, _] > 0}
```

but

```
Subscript[g, i_][x_] := 
  1/√(2 π Subscript[s, i]) Exp[-((x - Subscript[m, i])^2/(2 Subscript[s, i]))];

Simplify@Integrate[Subscript[g, i][x] Subscript[g, j][x], {x, -∞, ∞}]
```

still gives conditional expression for the integrand.
Any suggestion?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Patterned assumptions seem to need to match the `ConditionalExpression`'s condition *exactly* to work out for some cases.

The `∈ Reals`-assumptions do work as you gave them, while the inequality `Subscript[s,_]>0` does not, but observe the different behavior of `Subscript[s,_]>=0`:

Evaluating without any assumptions first:

```
f = 1/√(2 π Subscript[s, 
   i]) Exp[-((x - Subscript[m, i])^2/(2 Subscript[s, i]))]
expr=Integrate[f, {x, -∞, ∞}]
(* ConditionalExpression[1, Re[Subscript[s, i]] >= 0] *)
```

(Note, that the assumptions about `h`, `k` and `m` have no effect and are therefore superfluous.)

Now, bringing in the patterned assumptions in two versions:

```
greaterOnly = And @@ {Subscript[s, _] > 0, Element[Subscript[s, _], Reals]}
greaterEqual = And @@ {Subscript[s, _] >= 0, Element[Subscript[s, _], Reals]}

Refine[expr,greaterOnly]
(* ConditionalExpression[1, Subscript[s, i] >= 0] *) 
Refine[expr,greaterEqual]
(* 1 *)
```

So, the `Element`-part of assumptions is used in any case, while the inequality requires a "perfect" match.

Hope this helped!

> Note: The behavior seems to depend on the *Mathematica* version. The code above works in 10.1, but behaves differently in 9.x and 8.x (see comments).

Comment: Which version are you using? In v9.0.1, both of the assumptions [failed](http://i.stack.imgur.com/NMWw0.png). And in v8.0.4, the result is [on the contrary](http://i.stack.imgur.com/TiAs6.png)!

Comment: @xzczd: I am using 10.1.

Answer (score 1):

The document never promises that pattern-matching is supported inside `Assumptions`. (Though in some cases it does seem to be!) So the only stable way I can think of is as following:

```
$Assumptions = {};(*This is to guarentee the Join below will work*)
Subscript[g, i_][x_] := 
    ($Assumptions = Union[$Assumptions~Join~
     {{Subscript[m, i], Subscript[s, i]} ∈ Reals, Subscript[s, i] > 0}]; 
   Exp[-((x - Subscript[m, i])^2/(2 Subscript[s, i]))]/Sqrt[2 π Subscript[s, i]]);

Simplify[Integrate[Subscript[g, i][x] Subscript[g, j][x], {x, -∞, ∞}]]
```

Tested in *v9.0.1* and *v12.3.1*, *Windows 10*.

Comment: This still gives a conditional expression in Mathematica 9.

Comment: @Fabio Well, the above code has been tested in v9.0.1, vista 32bit. Have you tried it with a fresh kernel?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I'm running Linux 64bit. Apparently, Mathematica behaves differently!

Comment: @Fabio Just encountered another example showing pattern-matching should be avoided in `Assumption`: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273665/1871

Comment: @xzczd: Well, it works as I demonstrated, i.e. with an exact match only, but in that case: 100%. Still true with 13.1.

Comment: That being said: Wolfram should strive to make it work reliably, as Patterns are such an ubiquitous feature of the Wolfram language, that it is hard to argument, why Mathematica is so very picky about its usage with assumptions