# Why does assuming f[_] > 0 does not work while Element[f[_], Reals] does?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, pattern-matching, assumptions, undocumented

`Refine` works with symbols in either way:

```
Refine[Sqrt[x^2], Element[x, Reals]]
(* Abs[x] *)

Refine[Sqrt[x^2], x > 0]
(* x *)
```

But assuming positive-valued arbitrary function `f[x]` does not work. (Real-valued `f[x]` works, though.)

```
Refine[Sqrt[f[x]^2], Element[f[_], Reals]] (*Works*)
(* Abs[f[x]] *)

Refine[Sqrt[f[x]^2], f[_] > 0] (*Does not work*)
(* Sqrt[f[x]^2] *)
```

How can I correctly assume that `f` is a positive-valued unary function?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in e.g. [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273665/1871) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/273665/1871) post:

**Though pattern matching seems to work in `$Assumption`/`Assumption` in some cases, one should avoid making use of this <strike>undocumented feature</strike> coincidence, because it's rather unstable.**

In OP's case, the only correct way to assume `f` is a positive-valued unary function I can think out is as follows:

```
(* Let's use a more general expression as example: *)
expr = Sum[Sqrt[f[Subscript[x, i]]^2], {i, 5}]
```

[image]

```
lst = Union@Cases[expr, f[_], Infinity]
```

[image]

```
assume = Table[var > 0, {var, lst}]
```

[image]

```
Refine[expr, assume]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using `Assuming` and `Refine`:

```
Assuming[Thread[Cases[#, f[_], Depth@#] > 0] &@#, Refine[#]] &@expr
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
  Assuming[f[_]>0, PowerExpand [Sqrt[f[x]^2] ]
```

It seems that the special task of the evaluation of nested powers is contained in PowerExpand.

Mathematica e.g. refrains from adding logs. The reason may be that simple formulas exist on Riemann surfaces only. The usual technique to cut a sheet off the Riemann surfaces as part of the complex plane is to a great part logically not extendable to a greater domain than just real positive maps $f: \mathbb R_+\to \mathbb R_+$

Comment: The `Assuming` is not doing anything. You get the same result with just `PowerExpand[Sqrt[f[x]^2]]`

Comment: True, but in most times the simplifying procedures contain more operations and its good practice to define domains.

Comment: Let me make the issue clearer: `Assuming[f[_] < 0, PowerExpand[Sqrt[f[x]^2]]]` still gives `f[x]` as output. This is because the default option value of `Assumptions` of `PowerExpand` is not `$Assumptions` but `Automatic`, while `Assuming` only influences value of `$Assumptions`. (See **Details** section of document of `PowerExpand` for more info. ) BTW, if you write `PowerExpand[Sqrt[f[x]^2], Assumptions -> f[_] < 0]`, the output will be `E^(I \[Pi] Floor[1/2 - Arg[f[x]]/\[Pi]]) f[x]`, still undesired.